# The number of values of $f(x)/x$ when $f$ is a linearized polynomial

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Consider an $\mathbb{F}_q$-linear map $f:\mathbb{F}_{q^n}\to \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ (so  $f$ is a linearized polynomial). Suppose also that $f$ is not $\mathbb{F}_{q^i}$-linear, where $i>1$.

My question is about the number of values that the function $f(x)/x$ can take, where $x$ is a nonzero element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$. The upper bound $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$ follows easily (since $\frac{f(\lambda x)}{\lambda x}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ if $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{F}_q^*$). For the lower bound, I can use a result of S. Ball (The number of directions determined by a function over a finite field, J. Combin. Theory Ser. A, 104 (2003) 341--350), and find $q^{n-1}+1$.

I have two questions:

(a) I believe there should be a way to avoid the heavy machinery used in the last paper to deduce the lower bound immediately. Does anyone see how?

(b) My actual question is what happens if I restrict the map $f$ to values $x$ in some $\mathbb{F}_q$-subspace $V$ of dimension $k$ of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$. I would guess that the lower and upper bounds are then $q^{k-1}+1$ and $\frac{q^k-1}{q-1}$ but I do not find a reference for this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: As pointed out below, the lower bound can be one if there are no extra conditions. However, in practice, I assume that there is at least one direction $f(y)/y$ that is only determined $q-1$ times (namely, by $y\in V$ and its $\mathbb{F}_q^*$-multiples).

Comment: Your second question implies that the lower bound becomes lower when adding an extra constraint; shouldn't that be impossible?

Comment: I do not really see why that is impossible. If $x$ doesn't run through the whole field, you have less points (of the form (x,f(x)), so this smaller set of points will determine less directions. No?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood; I thought you were talking about restricting the output, not the input. My apologies.

Comment: This may help: a $\mathbb{F}_q$-linear function $f: \mathbb{F}_{q^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ has a unique expression of the form $\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} a_i x^{q^i}, a_i \in \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$.

Comment: Yes, I know that $f$ is a linearized polynomial. I do not know how this helps to answer my question, unfortunately.

Comment: This direction that has a unique output would have to be in the sub space, right? Otherwise, my answer below still does work.

Comment: Yes, I'll modify the statement a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the second part of your question.

The upper bound seems obvious, for the same reason as in the original case. The lower bound, however, is 1.

There is some linear map that sends the chosen subspace to 0, but is not itself 0. This then gives slope 0 on that entire subspace, giving an answer of 1.

I did find something interesting when looking for an example, which the above answer does not explain. When trying for $\mathbb{F}_8$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with a subspace generated by $1, \alpha$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_8$, the polynomial $x^4 + (\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1) x^2 + (\alpha^2 + \alpha)x$ worked no matter which $\alpha$ was chosen. This may be an artifact of a small example, but I'd be interested to see whether the coefficients of the polynomial could be chosen in terms of the subspace in a polynomial manner (or if that even makes sense).

Edited for more I figured out about the second half of my answer:

This isn't hard to prove by induction, if you take "in terms of the subspace" to mean "in terms of a basis of the sub space". The base case is the 0-dimensional point, which corresponds to the polynomial $x$. Then if we are adding $\alpha$ to a subspace with polynomial $P(X)$, the new polynomial will be $P(X)^q - P(\alpha)^{q-1}P(X)$. So for example, for the above: $P_1 = X^2+X$, so $P_{1, \alpha} = X^4+X^2+(\alpha^2+\alpha)(X^2+X)$, as above. This always gives a monic polynomial, and in fact is the unique monic linearized polynomial of minimal degree. More generally, define the Lang map $L$ by $L(x) = x^{q-1}$. Then the polynomial for the sub space generated by $\{\alpha_i\}$ is $(\prod_i (Frob - L(\alpha_i))) X$.

Comment: Very good point about the lower bound, thanks! I clearly translated my geometrical problem in the wrong way to a statement about q-polynomials and should restate my original question (a polynomial only determining one direction does not give my the required geometric structure).

Comment: For the second remark: would you be able to do the same with a subspace generated by, say $1,\alpha$ and $\beta$? If only $\alpha$ is involved, I am not too surprised that you can write down a polynomial vanishing on a subspace explicitly without saying anything more about $\alpha$. But it will become tricky to do this in general I suspect.

Comment: I added some information answering how to calculate the relevant polynomial in general.