# A polynomial in multiple variables with nice properties

Tags: nt.number-theory

After answering another question ([The number of values of $f(x)/x$ when $f$ is a linearized polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268339/the-number-of-values-of-fx-x-when-f-is-a-linearized-polynomial)), I stumbled upon an interesting polynomial in multiple variables. Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the field of $q$ elements, and let $K$ be a field containing it. Then define 
\begin{equation}
L(X_1, X_2, ...) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n \text{Frob}^{i-1}(X_{\sigma(i)}).
\end{equation}
This polynomial is $\mathbb{F}_q$-multilinear, and detects whether the elements are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{F}_q$. In other words, it is nonzero exactly when they are linearly independent. I think this can be extended to the case where $K$ is an algebra, but haven't checked.

This seems interesting enough that I am guessing it's been found and used before; does this polynomial have a name, and is it used anywhere interesting?

Comment: I haven't checked whether your polynomial has the stated properties. One that does is the Moore determinant $\det (x_i^{q^{j-1}})$. The expansion of the determinant will look similar to your polynomial but will have signs in front of the product.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Ah whoops, you're right; I forgot to put signs in, thanks. That looks like it's exactly what I was looking for; I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a CW answer to remove this question from the unanswered list (once someone upvotes it). This is the determinant of the [Moore matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_matrix) $\left( x_i^{q^{j-1}} \right)_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$. This determinant can be expressed as a product of linear factors:
$$\det \left(x_i^{q^{j-1}} \right) = \prod_{(c_1:c_2:\cdots:c_n) \in \mathbb{F}_q \mathbb{P}^{n-1}} (c_1 x_1 + \cdots + c_n x_n),$$
up to a scalar factor depending on how we choose the representatives $(c_1, \ldots, c_n)\in \mathbb{F}_q^n$ of the points of $\mathbb{F}_q \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

That is just a generalization of the determinant. Let $n$ be the degree of $K$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $F := Frob$. Then the powers $(F^1,F^2,\ldots, F^n)$ are linearly independent as elements of $End_{\mathbb{F}_q}(K)$. In fact one can even show that 
$$End_{\mathbb{F}_q}(K) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n F^iK$$
(see for reference the proof of theorem 29.12 in Reiner: Maximal Orders).
On the other hand, $K$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of dimension $n$ and thus
$$End_{\mathbb{F}_q}(K) \cong \mathbb{F}_q^{n \times n}.$$
Understanding and working out these isomorphisms, you should come to the conclusion that your formula is nothing but the determinant on this matrix algebra. Thus your $n$ vectors are linearly indipendant if and only this determinant is non-zero.

This can of course be extended to other algebras (that are, among other things, also vector spaces), but as it is just a nice way to write the determinant, this should not be surprising.

Comment: This isn't simply the determinant, for several reasons. Mainly, I don't assume (as you do) that $deg K = n$; instead, $n$ can be any integer (though for $n > deg K$, the result is trivially 0). It is the determinant of the Moore matrix ( as pointed out in the comments above).

Comment: For $n > deg K$, the result gets trivial, yes. For $n < deg K$, the result is wrong. Take for example $n = 2 = q$ and $K = \mathbb{F}_8$. Then $L(x,y) = x + y^2 + y + x^2$ (no sign in characteristic $2$) and this has solutions in $\mathbb{F}_8$ that are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: In that case, $L(x, y) = xy^2 + x^2y$. The inner symbol is a product, not a sum; the formula is multi linear.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right...